# Outlook Issue - nothing in Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook 2013 and Mozilla Thunderbird as my e-mail clients. Everything works fine in Thunderbird but in Outlook I don't receive any new e-mails. I already checked all the settings, tried to remove and re-create profile in Outlook - but still, when I try to send e-mail to my account, I can only see it appear in Thunderbird but not in Outlook. I'm able to send e-mail from Outlook but I don't get any new e-mails in it (only in Thunderbird)

OS - Windows 8

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Which email service?

Comment: If your email provider supports IMAP, I suggest using that instead. It's much better for multiple email clients.

Comment: We use IMAP and I don't understand why this is happening. I can see mail is still on the server...but Outlook doesn't populate Inbox for some reason. I already re-checked all the settings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Thinderbird downloads messages first using POP3 and you can't download them using Outlook anymore. Either Thunderbird removes messages after download or you set up your POP3 server this way (for example, Gmail has the option to download POP3 messages once).

Comment: We use IMAP - all the mail stays on the server.